# In which android SDK API I should develop the app so that it works on all versions of android?

Tags: java, android

Which android version is highly used today? If I develop an app for Android 2.2 will it work in Jelly Bean? Is vice versa possible? In other words does Android OS supports upward compatibility or downward compatibility?

Comment: So if I develop an app for Jelly Bean, it will work on Froyo. Am I right?

Comment: no, it's the other way arround

Comment: an app of minimum SDK of value X, will work on all devices of X++, and not on X--

Answer (score 4):

> Which android version is highly used today?

Google [publishes this data every month](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), and it is reposted on seemingly every Android blog in existence.

> If I develop an app for Android 2.2 will it work in Jelly Bean?

Generally speaking, yes. However, it is entirely possible to write an app that breaks on newer versions of Android, particularly if you are doing things that are not officially supported.

> Is vice versa possible? In other words does Android OS supports upward compatibility or downward compatibility?

You can write an Android app that conditionally uses capabilities from newer versions of Android, yet remains backwards-compatible to older versions of Android. This is reminiscent of how you can write a Web site that uses newer HTML standards or browser features while still working on older/less capable browsers.

Comment: I removed my answer since you also had the data link, and in general provided better info :) so, +1

Answer (score 0):

I believe version 7 would be fine, since the majority (if not all) are using android at least 2.2, some research showed that nearly 80% of users are using android 2.2 and 2.3, the others are using 3.0+, so you will find like one in a hundred to be using some old stuff

Comment: And most tablets (and a lot of phones) have 4+, right?

Comment: yes if not android 3.0

Comment: I can't find version 7 in this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

Comment: Your stats are out of date, although it also depends on what geographic region you're targeting, if any. 2.2 is a tiny percentage.

Comment: yes it's based on some region

Comment: I am targeting Indian market

Comment: May I know where I can find region specific data

Comment: I'm sorry I meant version 8, FROYO, you can find all version by this Build.VERSION_CODES.,

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have access to that info, i just happen to pass by it long ago,